# @echo off doesn't work as it is supposed to, when combining the commands in one line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

As I just mentioned in the question, the `@echo off` command behaves very strange sometimes and doesn't work as we expect it to.

For instance, look at the following syntax I have in my batch file:

```dos
@echo off & set TIME=%TIME: =0% >nul & set DateTimeFn=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2% >nul & echo %DateTimeFn% & pause > nul
```

Now when I run that script, the only output I get is `ECHO is off.`.

I expect the desired `datetime` string as I have coded it in the file.

Can someone help me understand the problem, logic and a way out for this ?

Comment: Put @echo off on the first line by itself.

Comment: Yes tried that already and it does work, but my point is to make it work in one-liner, is there anyway for that ?, also why it doesn't work that way ?

Comment: You have a Delayed Expansion problem.  All variables are expanded before execution.  So you can't echo `%DateTimeFn%`.  You have to enable delayed expansion and reference your variable as `!DateTimeFn!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Delayed Expansion problem.  When a line of code in a batch file is executed all variables are first expanded to their values before any commands are executed.  To work around this you need to enable delayed expansion.  I have no idea why you would want to put all these commands on one line in a batch file but this will do what you want it to do.

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set TIME=%TIME: =0% >nul & set DateTimeFn=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_!TIME:~0,2!_!TIME:~3,2!_!TIME:~6,2! >nul & echo !DateTimeFn! & pause
```

Answer (score 1):

*Never* write to predefined or built-in variables like `DATE` or `TIME`! Once you write `TIME` as you do, `echo %TIME%` will no longer return the current system time but the value you assigned!

You should avoid reading `DATE` and `TIME` multiple times, because these values, like `RANDOM`, become expanded with individual values, so the first and the second values in `echo %TIME% %TIME%` might differ (to prove that, write a very long line `echo %TIME% %TIME% %TIME% ...`, so you might see different values).

Why are you writing all commands in a single line? As already pointed out by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51412154), this required [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Instead write every command in its own line, so normal `%`-expansion can be used:

```cmd
@echo off
set "Time0=%TIME: =0%"
set "Date_=%DATE%"
set "DateTimeFn=%Date_:~10,4%-%Date_:~4,2%-%Date_:~7,2%_%Time0:~0,2%_%Time0:~3,2%_%Time0:~6,2%"
echo %DateTimeFn%
pause > nul
```

You may have recognised the quoted `set` syntax which I recommend in order to avoid unwanted trailing spaces and also to protect special characters in the string, but not having the quotes `"`in the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You had a delayed expansion problem which have been addressed in Squashman's answer, but you should also note that `echo off` does not have any effect on its own line because the decision to whether or not do command echoing of current statement(s) is made before executing the line, based on prior state of **echo**, which is **on** by default.

It is just the `@` that turns echo off in your one-liner. You can achieve the same by removing `echo off` but keeping `@` at beginning of the line.

In fact `echo off` is redundant in a one-liner.